# Embedded files does not detect excel files

Tags: excel, vba, image, powerpoint

The code below was designed so that it could replace the embedded files with thier images in powerpoint presentation. However it was able to change the visio files and not the excel files in presentaion. Any idea why it does that?

```
enter code here

  Sub imagereplacement()


    With ActivePresentation
    z = .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
    MsgBox z, vbDefaultButton1, "Total Slides"
    End With


  For i = 1 To z
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
    s = .Shapes.Count
End With

    For c = 1 To s

        If sld.Shapes(c).Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(c).Copy
        Set newsh = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)
            With newsh
                .Left = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(c).Left
                .Top = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(c).Top

             Do
                .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
            Loop Until .ZOrderPosition = .ZOrderPosition
            End With

            For k = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
                If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(c) Is ActivePresentation.Slides(i).TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(k).Shape Then
                ActivePresentation.Slides(i).TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(k).Shape = newsh
                End If
            Next k

        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(c).Delete
        Else

        GoTo skip
        End If
    skip:

    Next c

   Next i
      MsgBox "Embedded files replaced by their Images", vbDefaultButton1

   End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to check this different angle of handling your issue: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/50628/easily-extract-images-text-and-embedded-files-from-an-office-2007-document/

Comment: There is no edit in the code i can make to make it work correct?

Comment: Try stepping backwards: `For c = s To 1 step -1`

Comment: still the problem persist